# how to Join 2 columns in numpy when they are list of lists?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Dataframe is:

```
            date             ids_x               ids_y
0     2011-04-23  [0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13]       []
1     2011-04-24  [0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13]       [12,4]
2     2011-04-25  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 12]          []
3     2011-04-26  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]           [4,5,6]
```

The convenient way, but slow way, is to use:

```
df['ids'] = df['ids_x'] + df['ids_y']
```

I want to achieve this method by `numpy`, for now it is very slow `4 seconds`. As `Pandas` use numpy I think I should use numpy without using `Pandas` in order to reduce the overhead.

I use `column_stack` but the output is:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

b = np.array([[9,8,7],[6,5,4,6,7,8]])

np.column_stack((a,b))

[out]: array([[1, 2, 3, [9, 8, 7]], [4, 5, 6, [6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)?

Comment: This may no be fast, however, `[np.append(x,y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]` works?

Comment: @JohnGalt I'm looking for a fast way as `df['something'] + df['another_thing']` would solve my problem without code complexity.

Comment: @Sven `concatenate` is not the solution as it merge the way I don't want to. I want something similar to `column_stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `np.column_stack` is that in `b` you don't have equal-length columns (and thus a `dtype` of `object`).

You can do this with `np.concatenate` (or as @John Galt said in comments `np.append`); e.g.:

```
In [43]: [np.concatenate((i,j)) for i,j in zip(a,b)])
Out[43]: [array([1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7]), array([4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8])]
```